# Replacing specific line of multiline textbox with another string

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to replace a line on my multiline textbox with some other string. First, I'm searching the textbox and if a match is found, then I'm trying to replace the whole line. However, my tests so far failed. Any ideas?

```
 If txtImageMap.Text.IndexOf(sSelectedControl, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 Then
            ' Found
            For i = 0 To txtImageMap.Lines.Length - 1
                If txtImageMap.Lines(i).StartsWith(sSelectedControl) Then
                    txtImageMap.Lines(i) = txtImageMap.Lines(i).Replace(txtImageMap.Lines(i), sEntry)
                End If
            Next
            txtImageMap.Refresh()
 End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite familiar with VB.Net but this might help:

```
Dim tempArray() as String
tempArray = txtImageMap.Lines

For i = 0 To tempArray.Length - 1
   If tempArray(i).StartsWith(sSelectedControl) Then
       tempArray(i) = tempArray(i).Replace(tempArray(i), sEntry)
   End If
Next

txtImageMap.Lines = tempArray
```

I've done the same thing in C#. (I guess it's the same proplem. Lines array is a readonly array so you have to go the way via tempArray)

Comment: any ideas if I want to add an extra line at the bottom?

Comment: @alwaysVBNET what i'd do: simply copy `txtImageMap.Lines` to an array with the size/length of `txtImageMap.Lines.Length + 1` and then reassign it to `txtImageMap.Lines`.